# lsFusion: dynamic change property headers on a form

Tags: open-source, lsfusion

Good afternoon. I can't find an example of how to
dynamically change property headers on a form?

I've tried to find the proper command in the documentation but not succeed yet. Is it
captionMyProp? how to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option `HEADER` of property (or action) being added to the form structure. Quote from the [documentation](https://docs.lsfusion.org/Properties_and_actions_block/#parameters):

> `HEADER propertyExpression`
>
> Specifying a property that determines the header for the column of the
> property (action) being added. The return value of this property will
> be used as the header. If the return value is `NULL`, then the added
> property (action) will be automatically hidden.

Example:

```
CLASS Operation;
type = DATA STRING (Operation);

CLASS Item;
name = DATA STRING (Item);

FORM Sample
    OBJECTS o=Operation, i=Item
    PROPERTIES(o) NEW, type
    PROPERTIES(i) NEW, name HEADER type(o) + ' result'
;
```

In the example above, the header of the `name` column will depend on the current value of the `Operation` object. It's also possible to make the header depend on the `Item` object itself.

Comment: Looked very simple and it works. Thank you!